# I am passing a string back to my controller then trying to do some raw sql on entity framework.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, rawsql

I was using linq but I ran into something that I need to write fast so I am trying to get raw sql to work. This is my first project in mvc so I am a newbie but here is my controller code

```
public ActionResult Index(string Vendors)
    {
        if (Vendors != "")
        {


            string query = "SELECT V.VENDOR_NAME, SUM(POL.ORDER_QTY * POL.UNIT_PRICE) AS AMOUNT_SPENT, MONTH(PO.ORDER_DATE) AS MO, YEAR(PO.ORDER_DATE) AS YR, M.ITEM_TYPE AS ITEM_TYPE "
                            + "FROM PO_LINE POL"
                            + "JOIN PURCH_ORD PO ON PO.PO_NUM = POL.PO_NUM"
                            + "JOIN VENDOR V ON V.VENDOR_ID = PO.VENDOR_ID"
                            + "JOIN MATERIAL M ON M.ITEM_ID = POL.ITEM_ID"
                            + "WHERE V.VENDOR_NAME =" + Vendors
                            + "GROUP BY V.VENDOR_NAME, M.ITEM_TYPE, YEAR(PO.ORDER_DATE), MONTH(PO.ORDER_DATE)"
                            + "ORDER BY V.VENDOR_NAME";

            var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<Reports>(query);
            ViewBag.Vendors = new SelectList(db.Vendors, "VENDOR_NAME", "VENDOR_NAME");
            return View(query.ToList());
        }
```

this is my modal code

```
           using System;
           using System.Collections.Generic;
           using System.Linq;
           using System.Text;


           namespace GreenfieldGroup2.Models.Reports
      {
         public class Reports
     {
    public string VENDOR_NAME { get; set; }
    public decimal AMOUNT_SPENT { get; set; }
    public string ITEM_TYPE { get; set; }
    public DateTime ORDER_DATE { get; set; }
    public string ITEM_NAME { get; set; }
    public int STOCK_QTY { get; set; }
    public string WARD_NAME { get; set; }
    public string WARD_LOCATION { get; set; }
    public int ITEM_ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DEL_DATE { get; set; }
}
```

}

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GreenfieldGroup2.Models.Reports.Reports]'.

is my error  I am not sure what this means. Below is my view Code

```
         @model IEnumerable<GreenfieldGroup2.Models.Reports.Reports>
      @{
         ViewBag.Title = "Index";
      }

     <br />
       <head>

<style>
    body {
    padding-top: 100px
    }
</style>
  </head>

    <body>
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "PurchasingReport", FormMethod.Get))
    {
       <table>
           <tr>
    <td align="left"><text>Select a Vendor:</text>

    </td>
    <td align="left">@Html.DropDownList("Vendors", "All Vendords")</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="Left">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onsubmit="return Verify()"/>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
}
<table border="1">
<tr>
   <th>

        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VENDOR_NAME)
       </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AMOUNT_SPENT)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITEM_TYPE)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ORDER_DATE)
    </th>


</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VENDOR_NAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AMOUNT_SPENT)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITEM_TYPE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ORDER_DATE)
        </td>

    </tr>
}
 </table>


 </body>
```

any help with would be gratefully appreciated this is for a school project

Comment: You should have at least **one space** at the end of each line of your SQL statement! Otherwise, you'll end up with SQL like this: `.....FROM PO_LINE POLJOIN PURCH_ORD .....` - not valid SQL .....

Comment: Oh no! Don't insert values that way! Never heard of [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)? Please use [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your return statement

```
return View(query.ToList());
```

to the following:

```
return View(data);
```

As I understand from the code you have posted, below

```
var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<Reports>(query);
```

you assign a reference to a sequence of `Reports`objects to the `data`. In other words a the type of `data` is `IEnumerable<GreenfieldGroup2.Models.Reports.Reports>` as I can infer from your code.

So that is needed to be passed to the View and not the sql statement, which is just a string.

Comment: This fixed my problem and I added the spaces like the guy said above. I also did add parameter query thank you all for responding it helped out a ton.

Comment: @JoshuaDeshazer you are welcome dude :) I am glad that I helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your view it expects "**@model IEnumerable**" and the parameter which you are passing to view is query that you are executing on database, rather than passing the query pass the **list**, which will work perfectly and will not give you the above error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was my final solution so if anybody else runs into this problem it works perfectly and no sql injections

```
        if (Vendors == null) { Vendors = ""; }
            if(Vendors == "") { Vendors = DBNull.Value.ToString(); }

            var @Vendor = new SqlParameter("@Vendor", Vendors);

            string query = "SELECT V.VENDOR_NAME, SUM(POL.ORDER_QTY * POL.UNIT_PRICE) AS AMOUNT_SPENT, MONTH(PO.ORDER_DATE) AS MO, YEAR(PO.ORDER_DATE) AS YR, M.ITEM_TYPE AS ITEM_TYPE "
                + "FROM PO_LINE POL "
                + "JOIN PURCH_ORD PO ON PO.PO_NUM = POL.PO_NUM "
                + "JOIN VENDOR V ON V.VENDOR_ID = PO.VENDOR_ID "
                + "JOIN MATERIAL M ON M.ITEM_ID = POL.ITEM_ID ";

            if (Vendors != "")
            {
                query += "WHERE V.VENDOR_NAME = @Vendor ";
            }

            query += "GROUP BY V.VENDOR_NAME, M.ITEM_TYPE, YEAR(PO.ORDER_DATE), MONTH(PO.ORDER_DATE) "
                + "ORDER BY V.VENDOR_NAME";


            if (Vendors != "")
            {
                var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<Reports>(query, @Vendor);
                return View(data.ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<Reports>(query);
                return View(data.ToList());
            }
```

Comment: Again I would like to thank everybody that answered my question this is my first program in mvc so my code may not be to clean; however, everyone that responded helped me got to my solution and pulling the correct data.